# Mechanical Turk: Categorization project via Request UI diffictulties

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am a newbie in MTurk, and I am trying to create a very simple Categorization Project via their Requester UI (rather then the API).

Each batch I use has 10 items (question and possible answer). I have searched their documentation and forums with not help and so I have several questions:

1. When i use their Standard Categorization template, I have no option for modifying the HTML and layout (as shown for ["Tagging of an image" project](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/RequesterUI/CreatingaHITTemplate.html)). the only formatting options are for the categories, instructions and includes/excludes. Is there a way to edit the HTML of the standard template they provide?
2. In the Standard Categorization template, while my input data file (csv file) contains 10 items, only 5 are shown (tried with 6, still only 5 are displayed in the preview). Is there a way to change this limitation?
3. When I try to use the "Create HITs Individually" (rather than the standard template, as explained above), I have the "Design Layout" options, but I cannot find a way to make the questions in the "form" required (which is possible via the API). Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you stick to the standard project templates, you can't modify them. That's the reason to create HITs individually (through the RUI or via the API).
2. You'll have to show us your CSV file, because it's not really clear from your description what the issues could be.
3. Your third question is unclear, but basically for creating HITs individually, you simply do standard HTML markup and put in `${variablename}` placeholders wherever you want one of your CSV upload variables to be placed.

If your project is at all large, I would definitely recommend going through the API. It's simply much more flexible than the RUI for creating any kind of customized design.